# How to write a axios get command correctly to curruncy rate api?

Tags: axios

I have a problem like this. I am new to react stuff. I used axios HTTP request npm package to write API call. But when I console log the response it says like this.

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data:
error: {code: 101, type: "missing_access_key", info: "You have not supplied an API Access Key. [Required format: access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY]"}
success: false
__proto__: Object
headers: {content-type: "application/json; Charset=UTF-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

It says that I am not providing API_key. This is how I have written my code.

```
 const access_key ='my_key'

    axios.get(`http://data.fixer.io/api/2013-12-24 
    ? access_key =${access_key}  & base = LKR & symbols = ETH`)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    })
```

Can Someone help me to solve this problem?. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*An alternative*

---

In case you're feeling tired of using a quite long string url which easily causes mistakes, the `axios` library already supports an alternative. Using like this:

```js
 const access_key ='my_key'
 axios.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/2013-12-24', {
        params: {
          access_key: access_key,
          base: LKR,
          symbols: ETH
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

---

For reference: https://github.com/axios/axios#example